# YouTube Analytics API for content owners

Tags: api, youtube, analytics

I implemented the Youtube Analytics API in js and everything is ok with that. I am the content owner and I want to get analytics for all channels and to allow login users to use their analytic. 
For example, when some users make login to my dashboard I pass their channel ids to YouTube and it is ok, they get their data. They have to authenticate to YouTube with popup every time they log in.
I want to know is there any way to avoid that and to allow them like content owner to see their data. 
I am using

```
window.onload = function () {
        setInitialDates();
        authenticate().then(loadClient).then(getDataFromAPI);
    }
    function authenticate() {
        return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
            .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly" })
            .then(function () {console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
                function (err) {console.error("Error signing in", err); });
    }
    function loadClient() {
        return gapi.client.load("https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2")
            .then(function () {console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); userLoaded = true; },
                function (err) {console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); userLoaded = false; });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question about not having to log-in each time, you would need do the 'server-side flow' method of authentication.

1. User clicks button in your app to authenticate with YouTube.
2. YouTube log-in opens, user logs in with google account.
3. User approves any permission scopes you enabled.
4. User redirected back to your app with tokens, you can save the 'refresh_token' in your database.
5. With the `refresh_token`, you can then generate an authentication token to make API calls.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization
https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/server-side-web-apps